# COM Objects while working in a background job

Tags: powershell, comobject

Trying to create a table in word and would like to speed up the process a bit, without jobs this works fine but it's just slow. When I run this script everything works fine except when the script gets to

```
$Table.Cell($x,<column>).Range.Text = <string>
```

It gives the error

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Cell:String) [], 
    RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

and when it gets to

```
$table = $doc.tables.item(1)
```

It gives the error

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (item:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
```

not taking all of the document's information...

Here's my code

```
#More code above
$owners = Import-CSV $ownerspath -header @("Owners")
foreach($name in $owners) {  
    #Document creation
    [ref]$SaveFormat = "microsoft.office.interop.word.WdSaveFormat" -as [type] 

    $Word = New-Object -comobject word.application
    $Word.Visible = $false
    $Doc = $Word.Documents.Add()
    $Range = $Doc.Range()

    $owner = $name.Owners
    $g = import-csv $exportpath$owner.csv -header @("Server name", "Description", "OS", "OS EOL", "SQL", "SQL EOL")
    $path = "$exportpath$owner.docx"

    if(($g.count + 1) -eq 1) {
        $rows = 2
    }
    else {
        $rows = $g.count + 1
    }

    #Table creation
    $Selection = $word.selection

    $Doc.Tables.Add($Range,$Rows,6) | Out-Null

    $Table = $Doc.Tables.item(1)

    $Table.Style = "Medium Shading 1 - Accent 1"    
    $Table.Cell(1,1).Range.Text = "Server name"
    $Table.Cell(1,2).Range.Text = "Server description"
    $Table.Cell(1,3).Range.Text = "OS Version"
    $Table.Cell(1,4).Range.Text = "OS EOL Date"
    $Table.Cell(1,5).Range.Text = "SQL Version"
    $Table.Cell(1,6).Range.Text = "SQL EOL Date"

    $x = 2
    foreach($l in $g) {
        $sn = $l.'Server name'
        $d = $l.Description
        $oper = $l.OS
        $opereol = $l.'OS EOL'
        $sequel = $l.SQL
        $sequeleol = $l.'SQL EOL'
        $scriptblock = {
            param($sn, $d, $oper, $opereol, $sequel, $sequeleol, $x)
            $word = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Word.Application')
            $doc = $word.documents
            $table = $doc.tables.item(1)
            #Server names, OS, OS EOL, SQL, SQL EOL, and coloring for the EOL dates if the need them are added in this foreach loop.
            $Table.Cell($x,1).Range.Text = $sn
            $Table.Cell($x,2).Range.Text = $d
            $Table.Cell($x,3).Range.Text = $oper
            if($l.'OS EOL' -eq 'Out of date') {
                $Table.Cell($x,4).Range.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 255
                $Table.Cell($x,4).Range.Text = $opereol
                $OoDTotal += 1
            }
            elseif($l.'OS EOL' -like "*!*") {
                $Table.Cell($x,4).Range.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 65535
                $Table.Cell($x,4).Range.Text = $opereol
                $CloseTotal += 1
            }
            else {
                $Table.Cell($x,4).Range.Text = $opereol
                $UtDTotal += 1
            }
            $Table.Cell($x,5).Range.Text = $sequel
            if($l.'SQL EOL' -eq 'Out of date') {
                $Table.Cell($x,6).Range.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 255
                $Table.Cell($x,6).Range.Text = $sequeleol
                $OoDTotal += 1
            }
            elseif($l.'SQL EOL' -like "*!*") {
                $Table.Cell($x,6).Range.shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 65535
                $Table.Cell($x,6).Range.Text = $sequeleol
                $CloseTotal += 1
            }
            else {
                $Table.Cell($x,6).Range.Text = $sequeleol
                $UtDTotal += 1
            }
        }
        Start-Job $scriptblock -ArgumentList $sn, $d, $oper, $opereol, $sequel, $sequeleol, $x
        $x++
    }
    while(get-job -state "Running") {
        start-sleep -seconds 1
    }
    Get-Job | Receive-Job
    Get-Job | Remove-Job

#More code below
```

EDIT: I am running this script on Posh V2 with Office Word 2007

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue.  You aren't passing in all of the necessary objects (e.g. at least and most specifically, the Word COM object) into your scriptblock.  PowerShell jobs actually create completely separate instances of the powershell process.  Go ahead and check:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { start-sleep -Seconds 20 }
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { start-sleep -Seconds 20 }

PS C:\Users\hiyo!> Get-Process powershell

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName                                                                                                
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     --  -- -----------                                                                                                
    388      22    40336      48820 ...54     0.45   2720   1 powershell                                                                                                 
    443      25    54360      66860 ...75     0.58   7240   1 powershell
```

And if you actually try to job this out the way you want and pass in all the right params, you might run into write-lock issues trying to open multiple instances of the file for R/W...